# Wordpress update_post_meta and array value issue

Tags: arrays, wordpress, metadata, frontend

i'm working on the function that will allow the user to post/edit/manage posts from front end and i'm stuck with the array updating.

```
update_post_meta($post_id, 'lapp_appmenu',$_POST['appmenu']);
```

This method works for the single values but fails when dealing with Array(when submitted it just removes the previously setted value).

Thank you in advance,

Nikola

EDIT:

the array is a unlimited list of items.

```
<?php
                    $i = 0;
                    if ($appmenu) {
                        foreach($appmenu as $row) { ?>
                            <li><span class="sort hndle">|||</span>
                                <input type="text" name="lapp_appmenu[<?php echo $i; ?>]" id="lapp_appmenu" value="<?php echo $row; ?>" size="30" />
                                <a class="repeatable-remove button" href="#">-</a></li>
                        <?php

                        $i++;
                        }
                    } else { ?>

                        <li><span class="sort hndle">|||</span>
                                    <input type="text" name="lapp_appmenu[<?php echo $i; ?>]" id="lapp_appmenu" value="" size="30" />
                                    <a class="repeatable-remove button" href="#">-</a></li>

                    <?php   }?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress stores the meta values as strings. When you pass `update_post_meta` an array, it automatically converts it to a string. What you'll need to do is `unserialize` it when you attempt to read the data.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta (explains that the value is converted to a string)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php